# Android 5.0 force stop behavior

Tags: android, broadcast, android-5.0-lollipop

Just update to Android 5.0 by OTA. The biggest find is that if a user Force Stop my app(in System Setting), my app stops right now. And my app cannot receive any broadcast anymore, even if my receiver is registered in AndroidManifest.xml. More surprisingly, when the user reboot the device, my app even cannot receive android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

Does anyone pay attention to this?

Comment: Yes, I also realized another odd behavior: after Force Stop, if I open again my app some images are missing (black background is showed) unless I clear data or restart the device. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I just noticed that on my Nexus 5, and I'm really loving it!
When the user "Force Stop" an app in Settings->Apps, it will be TOTALLY stopped and is black listed from receiving any broadcasts UNTIL the user open the app from the launcher.

I see it as a way like the "Disable" of system apps, you completely disable this app until you open it again.

I see this really very useful as I have lots of apps that are using unnecessary services in the background like Facebook for instance.